# HTML div not appearing

Tags: html

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to build a website with various links in the same line. I'm using div so I got them all on the same block. The problem is that when I put all the links on float:left, the background color dissappears, but when I put the last link with float:center it shows the background as I want it.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

This is what I'm using:

```
<div id="links" style="width:1250;height:450;background-color:#000000;text-align:center">

<ul type="none">
<li style="float:left;margin-right:100px;text-align:center">
<a href="Desafio.html" target="_blank">Nosotros</a>
</li>
<li style="float:left;margin-right:100px">
<a href="Desafio.html" target="_blank">Desafío UNIMET</a>
</li>
<li style="float:left;margin-right:100px">
<a href="Desafio.html" target="_blank">Patrocinantes</a>
</li>
<li style="float:left;margin-right:100px">
<a href="Desafio.html" target="_blank">Contacto</a>
</li>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: Try: `display: block`

Comment: you need to clear the floats

Comment: HTML and CSS are just nasty. Not very helpful, I know, but it still had to be said.

Comment: And may I add, "hackish".

Comment: There are a lot of little issues with your code the way it is currently. I just want to suggest moving your css into some `<style></style>` tags and ensuring your values are declared appropriately. Also `float:left; clear:right;` might save you a lot of heart ache.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as float: center only left, right, none, and inherit.  But the reason the parent container bg color is not showing is because when you float an element it no longer takes up space in its parent.

Either give your parent container a height (and specify pixels or some other unit of measure which you aren't doing now), or as a hack you can give the parent: "overflow: hidden;" css property.

Good luck in your learnings!  Time and passion will get you everwhere!

EDIT:  I highly recommend you get the book CSS Mastery by Andy Budd.  It will teach you this and a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

You had not given the unit to `width`, and `height`. Make it to `px` or `em` or as per what you need and it will work.

```
<div id="links" style="width:1250px;height:450px;background-color:#000000;text-align:center">

<ul type="none">
<li style="float:left;margin-right:100px;text-align:center">
<a href="Desafio.html" target="_blank">Nosotros</a>
</li>
<li style="float:left;margin-right:100px">
<a href="Desafio.html" target="_blank">Desafío UNIMET</a>
</li>
<li style="float:left;margin-right:100px">
<a href="Desafio.html" target="_blank">Patrocinantes</a>
</li>
<li style="float:left;margin-right:100px">
<a href="Desafio.html" target="_blank">Contacto</a>
</li>
</ul></div>
```

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/sLEYs/

Secondly, there is no such value `center` for float. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp